# Why an array of objects are updated when it should not?

Tags: c#

Below are my program.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    GetObjectList();
}

private static IEnumerable<object?[]> GetObjectList()
{
    var objectArray = new object?[]
    {
        "Item 1",
        "Item 2",
        "Item 3",
    };

    return SetupObjectList(objectArray);
}

private static List<object?[]> SetupObjectList(object?[] objectArray)
{
    var list = new List<object?[]>();

    for (int i = 0; i < objectArray.Length; i++)
    {
        var newObjectArray = objectArray;

        foreach(var item in newObjectArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Old: " + item?.ToString());
        }

        newObjectArray[i] = "NULL";

        foreach(var item in newObjectArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("New: " + item?.ToString());
        }

        list.Add(newObjectArray);

        Console.WriteLine("Item added");
    }
    return list;
}
```

Below are the output from above program:

```
Old: Item 1
Old: Item 2
Old: Item 3
New: NULL
New: Item 2
New: Item 3
Item added

Old: NULL
Old: Item 2
Old: Item 3
New: NULL
New: NULL
New: Item 3
Item added

Old: NULL
Old: NULL
Old: Item 3
New: NULL
New: NULL
New: NULL
Item added
```

The question is, why the old values were replaced with null? I did not update ObjectArray[i] to "NULL" but the value still updated to "NULL". I only wish to update the newObjectArray array. Do I missed anything?

To be clear, my expected outcome is as below:

```
Old: Item 1
Old: Item 2
Old: Item 3
New: NULL
New: Item 2
New: Item 3
Item added

Old: Item 1
Old: Item 2
Old: Item 3
New: Item 1
New: NULL
New: Item 3
Item added

Old: Item 1
Old: Item 2
Old: Item 3
New: Item 1
New: Item 2
New: NULL
Item added
```

Comment: You have one array in all of your code: the one initially instantiated as `objectArray`. With the line `var newObjectArray = objectArray;`, `SetupObjectList` has two references to that same array.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar - Exactly. And I assume that Akmal wanted to copy objectArray into newObjectArray rather than setting up a reference. To create a **copy,** use `var newObjArray = new object[objectArray.Length]; Array.Copy(objectArray, newObjArray, objectArray.Length);`

Comment: Let me add that there is also the LINQ-way of creating a copy of objectArray: `var newObjArray2 = objectArray.Select(s=>s).ToArray();`. It is even possible to omit the .Select, it's sufficient to do  `var newObjArray = objectArray.ToArray();` to create a copy of all items (because it converts from `IEnumerable<object>`).

Comment: Thank you Matt. This is what exactly what I'm looking for. I didn't know that copying an array to another is different to how we do it with variable.